# How to create a javascript array with data from Ruby On Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am working with a JS array that looks like this:

```
var MapPoints = '[
 {"address":{"address":"plac Grzybowski, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2360592","lng":"21.002903599999968"},"title":"Warszawa"},
 {"address":{"address":"Jana Paw\u0142a II, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2179967","lng":"21.222655600000053"},"title":"Wroc\u0142aw"},
 {"address":{"address":"Wawelska, Warszawa, Polska","lat":"52.2166692","lng":"20.993677599999955"},"title":"O\u015bwi\u0119cim"}]';
```

How to create such an array with data populated from a Ruby On Rails model?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) is useful with accessing Rails variables within your JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just erb it into place:

```
var MapPoints = <%= raw @map_points.to_json %>
```